# How to pass nested view model objects as dropdown in razor

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I have been learning to program for less than a year. I am trying to build a mock car inventory management website using asp.net framework. I have built simpler websites using these same techs?, but have never been exposed to a problem that requires such a complex solution combining different techs, and am very confused. After searching around for an answer for hours, I can't find a solution similar enough to understand where I am going wrong, or what I am missing conceptually that I don't understand where to go next. My instructors have been no help and every step of the way just default to "do it how you have on other projects", but I have never done this with complex view models in razor. Because of that I think I have a poor understanding of what is going on, and how these are supposed to work together to make good web pages.

I am using razor pages to make an add Car form. Initially I was trying to populate dropdowns with my model.

```
    {
        public Car Car { get; set; }
        public List<Make> Makes { get; set; }
        public List<BodyStyle> BodyStyles { get; set; }
        public List<Transmission> Transmissions { get; set; }
        public List<Color> Colors { get; set; }
        public List<Interior> Interiors { get; set; }
    }
```

These are all nested Classes. All of them have and id and name property, but Model and Car the most complex.

```
    {
        public int ModelId { get; set; }
        public Make Make { get; set; }
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
        public string AddedByEmail { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        public BodyStyle BodyStyle { get; set; }
        public Interior Interior { get; set; }
        public Color Color { get; set; }
        public Model Model { get; set; }
        public Transmission Transmission { get; set; }
        public int YearBuilt { get; set; }
        public bool IsNew { get; set; }
        public int Mileage { get; set; }
        public string VIN { get; set; }
        public decimal MSRP { get; set; }
        public decimal ListPrice { get; set; }
        public string Info { get; set; }
        public string PictureLink { get; set; }
        public bool IsFeatured { get; set; }
    }
```

To populate them I did what I would do in the past, something like this.

```
<h2>Add Vehicle</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddVehicle", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "AddCar", @class = "col-12 row" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary();
    <div class="col-4">
        <label class="form-label" for="MakeId">Make</label>
        <select id="MakeId" name="MakeId" class="form-select">
            <option selected disabled>Select Make</option>
            @foreach (var make in Model.Makes)
            {
                <option value="@make.MakeId">@make.MakeName</option>
            }
        </select>
        <label class="form-label" for="Type">Type</label>
        <select name="isNew" class="form-select">
            <option value="true">New</option>
            <option value="false">Used</option>
        </select>
        <label class="form-label" for="Year">Year</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="Year" name="Year" type="text" />
        <label class="form-label" for="Color">Color</label>
        <select id="colorId" name="Color" class="form-select">
            @foreach (var color in Model.Colors)
            {
                <option value="@color.ColorId">@color.ColorName</option>
            }
        </select>
```

Ect. The form is longer but you get the idea. My next goal was to filter the Models dropdown to only show the models based on the selected make. Again I did this how I would in the past using ajax.

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $("#MakeId").on("change", function () {
            var selected = $(this).val();
            GetModels(selected);
        })
    </script>

    <script>
        function GetModels(value) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'https://localhost:44306/Admin/GetModels/',
                data: { makeId: value },
                success: function (models) {
                    var html = '';
                    $.each(models, function (index, model) {
                        html += "<option value=" + model.ModelId + ">" + model.ModelName + "/option>";
                    });
                    $('#ModelId').empty();
                    $('#ModelId').append(html.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

So now you know how I got here. The real question I have is now that I am working on posting the entered and selected data, how do I get the nested objects to return anything but null? Even dropdowns for a bool like 'IsNew' works, but none of my nested objects do, and my understand of razor, ajax, and the model controller interaction is not deep enough yet to know what I am missing , or where to go next. All of there solutions I can find are either so simple they do not help, or too complex that I do not understand what is going on. Additionally a lot of awnsers are for API controllers or .Net Core. This is my MVC controller in .net Framework for this page:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        // add
        public ActionResult AddVehicle()
        {
            var avm = new AddVM();
            var _mrepo = RepoFactory.GetMakeRepo();
            var _crepo = RepoFactory.GetColorRepo();
            var _bsrepo = RepoFactory.GetBodyStyleRepo();
            var _trepo = RepoFactory.GetTransmissionRepo();
            var _irepo = RepoFactory.GetInteriorRepo();


            avm.Makes = _mrepo.GetMakes();
            avm.Colors = _crepo.GetColors();
            avm.BodyStyles = _bsrepo.GetBodyStyles();
            avm.Transmissions = _trepo.GetTransmissions();
            avm.Interiors = _irepo.GetInteriors();


            return View(avm);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("admin/GetModels/{makeId}")]
        public JsonResult GetModels(int makeId)
        {
            var _mrepo = RepoFactory.GetModelRepo();
            var makes = _mrepo.GetModelsByMake(makeId);

            return Json(makes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("admin/GetModels")]
        public ActionResult AddVehicle(Car car)
        {
            var _crepo = RepoFactory.GetCarRepo();
            _crepo.AddCar(car);
            return View("EditCar", car);
        }
```

After searching and reading a ton on Model Binding, or how to do it in Json with ajax, ect. I am just confused as to which direction to go into. It seems like I can not find another solution that won't destroy my filtering or the way my layout is done. Sorry for the legnth, first post on SOF. Any help would be extremely appreciated from a frustrated new programmer trying to learn.

Comment: There is no `MakeId` property in your car model, so the value of `MakeId` has nowhere to bind to.  `isNew` does have a property to bind to in your car model, and that is why you see it being bound.  For a nested object, the property name would have periods to signify object boundarys.  Ex. class Make { int Id; } on class Car { Make Make; } would have a name/id like  "Make.Id"  to bind to the id of the make of the car you are posting.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I didn't include the Make class for length, but it has the properties of MakeId and MakeName, as well as a few other but they are not relevant for this form. So my end goal is to get the Car that my controller inherits assigned so that car.model.make.makeId has a value, or the even simpler, car.color.colorId has value. Right now I just get back Make = null and Color = null.

Comment: id="colorId"  should be  id="Color.ColorId"  so that the binder knows ColorId is a property that belongs to the Color property of the binding model.

Comment: sorry for the late reply @hijinxbassist , the suggestion did not work. I am going to make another post about this topic. I have similar pages with simpler versions of the same problem going on, and still have not had luck with the easier versions of this problem.